# xcode - refresh tableview after called method from anther class

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, uitableview

i create button to add student , i make method handle that by showing pop menu(alert view)
then get the code entered in variable called result (NSString) then called web service get required data from my web service

```
- (IBAction)add_button:(id)sender {
        [self addStudent];
    }

- (void) addStudent {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Add Student" message:@"Enter Connection Code" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Dismiss" otherButtonTitles:@"Add", nil];
        [alert setAlertViewStyle:UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput];
        [alert show];
    }

 -(void) alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{
        result = [[alertView textFieldAtIndex:0] text];
        NSLog(@"the result connection code %@",result);
        WebService *web = [[WebService alloc]init];
        [web retriveDataWithCodeAndUrl:result Andurl:STUDENT_URL];
    }
```

in web service class
after finish loading and get required data 
i need back my tableview and refresh it with new data 
i try protocol but it doent work so i try make instance of my tableview class
, i try also make notification to handle it and refresh view 
(webservice class)

```
-(void) connectionDidFinishLoading :(NSURLConnection *) connection{
    NSLog(@"data finish loading ");
    School_TableViewController *home = [[School_TableViewController alloc]init];
    [home didFinishWithData:respone];
    [[self delegate]didFinishLoadingwithData:respone];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
     postNotificationName:@"TestNotification"
     object:self];
     }
```

back to my table view class to handle notification and refresh table

```
- (void) receiveTestNotification:(NSNotification *) notification
{
    if ([[notification name] isEqualToString:@"TestNotification"])
        NSLog (@"Successfully received the test notification!");
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

but it dosnt work , i need nice way to communicate between singleton and tableview 
and method to refresh view

thank you in advance

Comment: As u are not passing any newdata to ur tableview. Your simply calling reload method with old data. So when u get the response for webservice parse it or simply pass it as per ur logic to tableview and then call reload.

Comment: i wasnt pass new data , i just fill my array with new data , but when it back to notification method it back nil(names array) , i pass new data within my notification method

Comment: ur sending "self" in notification and no data ,and also I don't see where that newdata is filling up the array in receiveTestNotification method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Certainly It doen't work because you didn't update data for your `tableView`

and I wonder why you didn't use the `delegate didFinishLoadingwithData`

use delegate:

-In School_TableViewController.h:

```
@interface School_TableViewController : UITableViewController <YourWebServiceDelegate>
```

-In School_TableViewController.m:

```
 -(void) didFinishLoadingwithData:(NSData*) data {
        // Do parse respone data method and update yourTableViewData
            yourtableViewData = notification.object
            [self.tableView reloadData];
    }
```

or try

-In service class

```
-(void) connectionDidFinishLoading :(NSURLConnection *) connection{
    NSLog(@"data finish loading ");
/* remove this code you don't need alloc School_TableViewController
        School_TableViewController *home = [[School_TableViewController alloc]init];
        [home didFinishWithData:respone];
*/
    [[self delegate]didFinishLoadingwithData:respone];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
     postNotificationName:@"TestNotification"
         object:response];
 }
```

-In your tableView

```
- (void) receiveTestNotification:(NSNotification *) notification
{
    if ([[notification name] isEqualToString:@"TestNotification"])
        NSLog (@"Successfully received the test notification!");
  // Do parse respone data method and update yourTableViewData
    yourtableViewData = notification.object
    [self.tableView reloadData];

}
```

Comment: my delegate dosnt work , i wish know why ? the other way work but please explain more how to use delegate to pass data

Comment: I think you didn't have webservice.delegate = self in School_TableViewController so your delegate can't work fine.
I'm sorry because I'm not good at Eng and explain it
you should try read https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/general/conceptual/devpedia-cocoacore/Protocol.html